# How to remove data-target and data-toggle from child elements or disable elements from triggering the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="card_{{_id}}" class="card-panel" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{_id}}">
      <span class="white-text">{{text}}</span>
      <div class="card-action">
        {{#each tags}}
        <div class="chip">
          <tag class="tag">{{this}}</tag>
          <i id="removeTag" class="material-icons fa fa-ban"></i>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
        <div class="chip" id="likeButton">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>&nbsp;{{likes}}&nbsp;&nbsp; Likes
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

above is sample html code from my meteor project. i want the `div#card` element to activate the `modal` by clicking on it. But i do not want the `div.chip` elements to toggle the `modal` when clicked. Is there a way i can disable child element from the `data-toggle` of the modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use javascript, you can do `stopPropagation` for stopping click event on `div.chip` from bubbling to `div#card`.

```
$('.chip').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

For elements in a meteor template, you do something like this (replace yourTemplate with your template name),

```
Template.yourTemplate.events({
    'click .div', function (ev, template) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1225/)

Comment: I tried this and it's not working for me.  Here is my codepen demonstrating this: https://codepen.io/jeremymoritz/pen/qBxJGbV